# cannot use textcolor and line breaks simultaneously in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am encountering an error in the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary {patterns}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw [] (0,0) node [label={[align=center]{\textcolor{red}{Line1 \\ Line2}}}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\textcolor{red}{Line1 \\Line2};
\end{document}
```

If I remove either `\\` or `\textcolor{red}` it works. Weird thing is that outside of \tikzpicture, `{\textcolor{red}{Line1 \\ Line2}}` works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why. You can change the color of all the text by having the option outside. -or you can change part of the text to another color -as long as that part does not have line breaks.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) node[label={[align=center, red]{Line1\\Line2}}] {};
\draw (0,0) node[label={[align=center]{\textcolor{red}{Line1}\\Line2}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red and black text]